# ImportError: cannot import name 'user_list' from 'analysis'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

для ускорения работы функции использовала мультипроцессинг. а затем поставляю данные для получения нужного результата в метод и получаю некий список. как этот список импортировать в другой py-файл подскажите пожалуйста. спасибо за помощь.
1 файл(analysis.py):

```
def find_users(text):
    bla-bla
    return u_list

class T:
    def __init__(self):
        bla
    def find_text(self, arg):
        bla-bla
        return text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = T()
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=)
    pool.map(t.find_text, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    u_list = find_users(t.tweets))
```

во 2 файл нужно импортировать u_list из 1 файла.
from analysis import u_list - не работает.

Comment: `2 файл в который нужно импортировать
from analysis import u_list - не работает` - это содержимое файла или то как вы импортируете этот файл в первом файле?

Comment: извините, некорректно указала, импорт не работает, а соответственно и файл не отрабатывает. ошибка в импорте

Comment: Какие у вас модули в принципе есть? Как первый модуль называется? Какое содержимое у второго модуля (analysis.py) - есть ли там u_list вообще? Добавьте точный текст ошибки без перевода и со стектрейсом.

Comment: указала ошибку импорта

Comment: Если запускаете 2-й файл, то он не увидит `u_list` из первого, потому что условие `if __name__ == __main__`. У вас проблема описана не очень подробно, как и не видно полного текста ошибки, поэтому сложно сказать

Comment: Полный стектрейс нужен, а не только заголовок, чтобы понимать что из чего у вас вызывается.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~\file.py", line 9, in <module>
    from analysis import user_list
ImportError: cannot import name 'user_list' from 'analysis' (путь к файлу). если это как-то помогло.    я понимаю, что оно в if __name__ == __main__. по другому не пойдет мультипроцессинг. но мне нужно что я могла код запустить из файла, в который я импортирую u_list. я думала кто-то знает, как это обойти